# Community promotion ad -elementary OS

Tags: discussion

In my opinion, elementary OS __  participate in Community promotion ad and publish its ad at

https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12379/community-promotion-ads-2015.

Also after reading a post in **meta** , [How do we get Community Promotion Ads on beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites), I guess it is possible to us to start community promotion ads in our site, isn't it ?

*EDIT*:

Here is our community-promotion-ad: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14695/186134

Comment: I doubt the community is large enough yet for the ads here, but one on Ask Ubuntu would be good. It's unlikely to make it for this year (it could) but we may as well try - and repost next year.

Comment: @Tim hello, wow good to see you here :) Very active user =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: elementary OS Stack Exchange]

Comment: have you posted?  Or are you waiting for any improvements?

Comment: @Ravan waiting for votes / suggestions / approval from devs / mods. Will wait 48 hours.

Comment: please post it =) have you posted?

Comment: @Ravan  will when I get home, i.stack.imgur.com is blocked here.

Comment: Still I don't find our promotion ad :)

Comment: @Ravan http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14695/186134